# Send Parameter on Remote attribute in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to send a parameter (not field name) from a `Model` class to `Controller` using `Remote` attribute.

For example, I've this `Model` class:

```
public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ClassName
    {
        get { return "SubCategory"; }
    }
    [StringLength(450)]
    [Remote("IsSubCategoryExist", "Products", AdditionalFields = "ID, ClassName",
            ErrorMessage = "Product name already exists")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to send this class name `SubCategory` as a parameter to `IsSubCategoryExist` method in the `Products` controller when `Remote` is triggered. Can it be achieved?

**Update:**

Controller code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> IsSubCategoryExist(string Name, int? ID, string ClassName)
{
      var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == ClassName);

      if (type != null)
      {
         DbSet dbSet = _dbContext.Set(type);

         List<object> subCategories;
         if(ID == null)
         {
             subCategories = await dbSet.Where("Name == @0", Name) 
                                        .Take(1).ToListAsync();
         }
         else
         {
             subCategories = await dbSet.Where("Name == @0 and Id != @1", Name,ID)
                                        .Take(1).ToListAsync();
         }

         if(subCategories.Count > 0)
         {
            return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
         return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     else
     {
        throw new Exception("Table name does not exist with the provided name");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with doing following:

```
public string ClassName { get {return "SubCategory";} }

[Remote("IsSubCategoryExist", "Products", AdditionalFields = "ID, ClassName",
        ErrorMessage = "Product name already exists")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

You have to put an hidden field in the form as follows otherwise it will give `ClassName is undefined` error:

```
Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClassName)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could add a field to your model with a static value, and then add it to AdditionalFields:

```
public string ClassName { get {return "SubCategory";} }

[Remote("IsSubCategoryExist", "Products", AdditionalFields = "ID, ClassName",
        ErrorMessage = "Product name already exists")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry `ClassName` is coming as "undefined" in the controller while in debug mode. I've updated `Controller` code above.

Comment: @RK This is because in you view there is no input field called `ClassName`. You can make a hidden input field in the form for ClassName.